# RadGrid - Rebind

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

I've a Radgrid and RadCombobox in a form. In a function i'm calling a forloop. In that forloop i'm using Rebind event for grid. In the loop, first time it was going to NeedDataSource of the grid, from the second time the Needdatasource event is not occuring,

When the Combobox text changes the Grid should go to NeedDataSource event. Plz help.

```
for (int a = 0; a < EmpCodecmb.Items.Count; a++)
        {            
            EmpCodecmb.Text = EmpCodecmb.Items[a].Text;
            EmpCodecmb.SelectedValue = EmpCodecmb.Items[a].Value;

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
        con.Open();
        cmd1.Connection = con;
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd1.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd1.CommandText = "get_EmpLeaveDetails";
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", EmpCodecmb.SelectedValue);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedMonth", commonDatetime);
        SqlDataReader sdp1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdp1.Read())
        {
            CLtxt.Text = sdp1["CL"].ToString();
            ELtxt.Text = sdp1["EL"].ToString();
            LOPtxt.Text = sdp1["LOP"].ToString();
        }
        con.Close();

        Grid1.Rebind();
        Grid2.Rebind();

        Insert_f1();
        Insert_f2();
    }`
```

Comment: using rebind method in a for loop is not a good approach you should make your code more efficient.

Comment: IT would be better if you can create a DataTable before For Loop and add row to that using DataTable..Rows.Add() and then perform Bind

Comment: @Jigar Pandya, Thx Bro, it works gr8.. Thx a lot...

Answer (score 0):

I know its been some time since this was posted but, i think this might help:
http://nwije.blogspot.com/2011/04/telerik-radgrid-doesnt-fire.html